# Python: Skip user input and call later on

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and am currently just learning by making some scripts to use at work. Real simple, just takes user input and stores it in a string to be called later on. The questions are yes/no answers but I wish for the user to have the option to skip and for the question to be asked again at the end, how would I do this?

Currently this is what I've got:

```
import sys
yes = ('yes', 'y')
no = ('no', 'n')
skip = ('skip', 's')
power = str(raw_input("Does the site have power? (Yes/No): "))
if power.lower() in yes:
  pass
elif power.lower() in no:
  pass
elif power.lower() in skip:
  pass
else:
  print ''
  print '%s is an invlaid input! Please answer with Yes or No' % power
  print ''
  exit()
```

then at the end of the script after all the questions have been asked I have this:

```
if power.lower() in skip:
  power = str(raw_input("Does the site have power? (Yes/No): "))
  if power.lower() in yes:
    pass
  elif power.lower() in no:
    pass
  else:
    print ''
    print '%s is an invlaid input! Please answer with Yes or No' % power
    print ''
    exit()
else:
  pass

if power.lower == 'yes':
  print 'Site has power'
else:
  print 'Site doesnt have power, NFF.'
```

I understand this is very messy and I'm just looking for guidance/help.

Regards,
Trap.

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are off topic on StackOverflow. If you're looking for ways to improve your (working) code, consider posting a question over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How is this question unclear? The question makes perfect sense - OP wants to re-ask questions which are skipped by the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're rather new to Python I'll give you some tips:

1. Store all the questions which receive "skip" as a response into a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).
2. At the end of all your questions, iterate through (hint: "for" loop) all the questions which the user skipped and asked them again.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Display the sum
print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))
message=("is this correct")
Print=(message)
#store input
answer = input("yes/no:")
if answer == "yes": print("thank you")
if answer == "no": print("hmm, are you sure?")
#store input
answer = input("yes/no:")
if answer == "yes" : print("please call my suppot hotline: +47 476 58 266")
if answer == "no" : print("ok goodbye:)")


if someone had a solution for line 7 when answerd yes skiped to the end desplaing ok `goodbye:) thank you`
```